# How to group together numbers in a list by the value of their tens digit?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

The line `Table[Prime[n],{n,1000}]` produces the list of first 1000 primes. Given this list how can the values be grouped by the values of their tens digit? i.e. how to have the primes in 10s together. and then primes in 20s together and so on up to primes in 7900s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
m = 100;
table = Table[Prime[n], {n, m}];

GroupBy[table, IntegerDigits[#, 10, 6][[-2]] &]
```

> ```
> <|0 -> {2, 3, 5, 7, 101, 103, 107, 109, 307, 401, 409, 503, 509}, 
>  1 -> {11, 13, 17, 19, 113, 211, 311, 313, 317, 419}, 
>  2 -> {23, 29, 127, 223, 227, 229, 421, 521, 523}, 
>  3 -> {31, 37, 131, 137, 139, 233, 239, 331, 337, 431, 433, 439}, 
>  4 -> {41, 43, 47, 149, 241, 347, 349, 443, 449, 541}, 
>  5 -> {53, 59, 151, 157, 251, 257, 353, 359, 457}, 
>  6 -> {61, 67, 163, 167, 263, 269, 367, 461, 463, 467}, 
>  7 -> {71, 73, 79, 173, 179, 271, 277, 373, 379, 479}, 
>  8 -> {83, 89, 181, 281, 283, 383, 389, 487}, 
>  9 -> {97, 191, 193, 197, 199, 293, 397, 491, 499}|>
> ```

```
m = 1000;
table = Table[Prime[n], {n, m}];
GroupBy[table, IntegerDigits[#, 10, 6][[-2]] &] // Short[#, 10] &
```

> ```
> <|0->{2, 3, 5, 7, 101, 103, 107, 109, 307, 401, 409, 503, 509, 601,607, 
> 701, 709, 809, 907, 1009, 1103, 1109, 1201, 1301, 1303,1307, 1409,1601,1607, 
> 1609, 1709, 1801,1901,1907,2003,2203,2207,2309,2503, 2609,2707, 2801, 2803, 
> 2903, 2909,3001,3109,3203,3209,3301,3307,3407,3607,3701, 3709,3803, 3907, 
> 4001, 4003,4007,4201,4409,4507,4603,4703,4801,4903,4909,5003,5009, 5101, 
> 5107, 5209,5303,5309,5407,5501,5503,5507,5701,5801,5807,5903,6007,6101, 6203, 
> 6301, 6607,6701,6703,6709,6803,6907,7001,7103,7109,7207,7307,7309, 7507, 
> 7603, 7607,7703,7901,7907},
> <<8>>,
> 9 -> {97,191,193,197,199,293,397,491,499,593,599,691,797,991, 
> 997,1091,1093,1097,1193,1291,1297,1399,1493,1499,1597,1693,1697, 
> 1699,1993,1997,1999,2099,2293,2297,2393,<<28>>, 4691, 4793,4799,4993,4999, 
> 5099, 5197,5297,5393,5399,5591,5693,5791,5897,6091,6197,6199, 6299, 6397, 
> 6491, 6599,6691,6791,6793,6899,6991,6997,7193,7297,7393, 7499,7591, 7691, 
> 7699, 7793}|>
> ```

**Update:** Using `Mod[Quotient[#, 10], 10] &` instead of `IntegerDigits[...]` as suggested by J.M. in comments, is much faster for large `m`:

```
m = 1000000;
table = Table[Prime[n], {n, m}];
assoc1 = GroupBy[table, IntegerDigits[#, 10, 6][[-2]] &]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.196
> ```

```
assoc2 = GroupBy[table, Mod[Quotient[#, 10], 10] &]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.12
> ```

```
assoc1 == assoc2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: This should be a little bit faster: `GroupBy[Table[Prime[n], {n, 100}], Mod[Quotient[#, 10], 10] &]`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M.; great point. Updated with your suggestion.